# How to fetch GitLab merge requests with a specific reviewer using GitLab API?

Tags: javascript, gitlab

I am building a web application that uses the GitLab API to fetch merge requests. I would like to fetch merge requests with a specific reviewer, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do this using the GitLab API.

I am currently using the following endpoint to fetch merge requests:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:id/merge_requests
```

This endpoint returns all merge requests for the project, but I only want to fetch merge requests that have been reviewed by a specific user.

I have tried adding the following query parameter to the endpoint:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:id/merge_requests?reviewer_username=example_user
```

But this does not seem to work. I have also tried using the reviewer's user ID as a query parameter:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:id/merge_requests?reviewer_id=123
```

But this also does not work. I receive an empty array with status code 200.

I have looked through the GitLab API documentation, but I cannot find any information on how to fetch merge requests with a specific reviewer.

Can anyone help me figure out how to fetch GitLab merge requests with a specific reviewer using the GitLab API? I am using React on the front-end, but any guidance on the API endpoint or query parameters would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After trying to use the reviewer_username and reviewer_id query parameters with the GitLab API endpoint to fetch merge requests with a specific reviewer, I was still receiving an empty array with status code 200.

I eventually found a working solution by using the following endpoint:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:id/merge_requests?reviewer_id=123&state=opened&per_page=100&scope=all&non_archived=true&view=simple
```

where `:id` is the project ID and `123` is the ID of the reviewer.

I found this endpoint in the **GitLab Buddy Chrome extension** repository, and it works for me to fetch merge requests with a specific reviewer. The query parameters I used are:

- `reviewer_id`: the ID of the reviewer
- `state`: the state of the merge request, in this case opened
- `per_page`: the number of items to return per page, in this case 100
- `scope`: the scope of the merge requests to return, in this case all
- `non_archived`: whether to return merge requests from archived
  projects, in this case true
- `view`: the level of detail to return for each merge request, in this
  case simple

I hope this solution helps others who are trying to fetch GitLab merge requests with a specific reviewer using the GitLab API.

Comment: I believe the reason this worked is that you specified the per_page query parameter. I had the same issue and only added that parameter to my call  and it worked.